# Next & Previous Image doesn't work properly

Tags: 20.04, eog

Let's assume I have 15 images in a folder. I opened an image located in 10th index. When I hit (right key) or click the right/left arrow in an image they just don't work.

I have a feeling that it works alphabetically. But I want it to show according to my current folder sort preferences.